# Transforming an object array returned from observable into array of another type

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular-services, angular2-observables

The situation is like this: I have "mission service" returning an observable of Mission array:

```ts
  getMissions(): Observable<Mission[]> {
  return this.http.get<Mission[]>(this.MissionUrl).pipe(
    tap(_ => this.log('Fetched missions.')),
    catchError(this.handleError('getMissions: ', []))
  );
```

and this perfectly working subscriber function inside a component:

```ts
export class TreeViewerComponent implements OnInit {
  missions: Mission[];
  Nodes: Node[]=[];
  Edges: Edge[];

  constructor(private missionService: MissionService,
              private messageService: MessageService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
      this.getNodes();

  }

    getNodes(): void {
      this.missionService.getMissions()
      .subscribe(missions => {
          this.missions = missions;
          this.doThis();
        })
}

    doThis(): void{
      console.log('tree-viewer component1: '+this.missions);
      for (var i=0;i<this.missions.length;i++)
      {
        var tempNode= {id: this.missions[i].key, label: this.missions[i].Title};
        console.log(tempNode);
        this.Nodes.push(tempNode);
      }
      this.getEdges();
      this.wrapData();
    }
```

The problem is, it is not a good separation of concerns. The viewer component shouldn't deal with all this business logic. I want to separate the casting from type Mission (returning from the remote server) to type Node into another service.

How can I do it asynchronously?

**Edit after implementation suggestions:**

I'm still doing something wrong. I have two version of the getNodes method in treeHandlerService, as suggested. The first one is with the implentation @fmontes suggested, and indeed it is working:

```js
  getNodes(): void
  {
    this.missionService
        .getMissions()
        .pipe(
            flatMap((missions: Mission[]) => missions), // this will pass each mission to the map
            map((mission: Mission) => { // this will turn each Mission into a Node
                return new Node(mission.key, mission.Title) ;
            }),
            toArray() // this will group the nodes into an array of nodes
        )
        .subscribe((nodes: Node[]) => {
            this.Nodes = nodes;
            this.log('nodes: '+this.Nodes[0].label);//the log shows that it is working!
        });
  }
```

Alas, when I go to the component to read treeHandlerService.Nodes (the array that was updated asynchronously), it is still undefined (meaning the asynchronos activity haven't finished yet).

Another version is a shortened one, and I've tried to return the value immediately:

```js
  getNodes(): Observable<Node[]> {
    return this.missionService.getMissions().pipe(
      map((mission: Mission) => { // this will turn each Mission into a Node
          return new Node(mission.key, mission.Title) ;
      }),
      toArray()
    )
  };
```

But it doesn't even compile! I'm getting the following error:

```
ERROR in src/app/tree-handler.service.ts(39,7): error TS2345: Argument of type 'OperatorFunction<Mission, Node>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'OperatorFunction<Mission[], Node>'.
```

Type 'Mission' is not assignable to type 'Mission[]'.
    Property 'length' is missing in type 'Mission'.

Please Help guys...

Comment: use rxjs map/switchmap ...

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
// Don't forget to import the operators
import {map, flatMap, toArray} from 'rxjs/operators';


this.missionService
    .getMissions()
    .pipe(
        flatMap((missions: Mission[]) => missions), // this will pass each mission to the map
        map((mission: Mission) => { // this will turn each Mission into a Node
            return { id: mission.key, label: mission.Title };
        }),
        toArray() // this will group the nodes into an array of nodes
    )
    .subscribe((nodes: Node[]) => {
        this.nodes = nodes;
    });
```

Comment: Tnx @fmontes for your quick answer! Your code suggestion does look better than mine, but it looks as if I should still put it on the component itself. My initial design was to create TreeHandlerService which will do this operation, and then the component could call it without being aware to the existence of objects of any type other than Node & Edge. Is this a good direction? Could you show me how the new service will look like?

Comment: You can move that to the service itself and just make the method to return the Node[]

Answer (score 0):

I think it could be further simplified like this:

```
import { map, catchError } from 'rxjs/operators';

export class MissionService {

  ...

  getMissions(): Observable < Mission[] > {
    return this.http.get < Mission[] > (this.MissionUrl).pipe(
      map(missions => missions.map(mission => ({ 
        id: mission.key,
        label: mission.Title }) 
      )),
      catchError(this.handleError('getMissions: ', []))
    );
  }

  ...

}
```

Here, instead of additionally using the `flatMap` and `toArray` operators, I'm simply using the `map` operator of Rxjs with the `map` method on an array to do the needful.

And then in your Component Class:

```
export class TreeViewerComponent implements OnInit {
  missions: Mission[];
  Nodes: Node[] = [];
  Edges: Edge[];

  constructor(
    private missionService: MissionService,
    private messageService: MessageService
  ) {}

  ...

  getNodes(): void {
    this.missionService.getMissions()
      .subscribe(missions => {
        this.missions = missions;
      });
  }

  ...

}
```

Comment: Tnx guys, your answers does improve code simplicity & readability. I would still like that the TreeViewerComponent wouldn't have to deal with Mission objects, and be able to present completely other objects. So I want that another service, the TreeHandlerService, will take care of the business logic for him. SiddAjmera your implentation still make the component be aware of the Mission object. @fmontes if I return the Node[], will it already be loaded with data? When I have tried this earlier, it looked like the return occurs before the asynchronous action completes so the result is undefined.

Comment: Yes... I think what you need to do here is to create a service to get the node and THAT service is the one that use the MissionService to get the missions... or depending on you data and how is related, you can just create a new method in your MissionServices something like getMissionsAsNodes and move the code I comment into that method and then in your component you call that new method.

But like I said, it depends on how you data is related or structured.

Comment: Still not working :-(. I have edited the original question with all the additional data.

Comment: @Angular7Starter, it would be great if you could provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). You can use [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/fork/angular) to create one.

Comment: You're missing the `flatMap((missions: Mission[]) => missions)` before the map. That will pass ONE mission to the `map` right now you're passing an array of missions.